# Why my infix to postfix code using stack in c is not working correctly?

Tags: c

Today I have tried to write a code which convert infix expression to postfix expression, my code is running but not working properly,

I upload my whole code please let me know what is wrong with my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXSTACK 50

typedef char StackEntyType;
typedef enum{false, true}Boolean;

typedef struct{
        int top;
        StackEntyType entry[MAXSTACK];
}stack;
```

Creating a stack,

```
void CreateStack(stack *S){
    S->top = -1;
}
```

Checking is stack empty,

```
Boolean IsStackEmpty(stack *S){
    return S->top==-1;
}
```

Checking is stack full,

```
Boolean IsStackFull(stack *S){
    return S->top == MAXSTACK-1;
}
```

Code to push stack element,

```
void Push(StackEntyType item, stack *S){
    if(IsStackFull(&S)){
        printf("Stack is overflow\n");
    }else{
        S->entry[++S->top] = item;
    }
}
```

Code to Pop stack elements,

```
void Pop(StackEntyType *item, stack *S){
    if(IsStackEmpty(&S)){
        printf("Stack is underflow\n");
    }else{
        *item = S->entry[S->top--];
    }
}
```

code to return the top stack element,

```
char Peek(stack *S){
    return S->entry[S->top];
}
```

code to return operator precedence,

```
int Oprecedence(char elem){
    switch(elem){
        case '-':
        case '+':
            return 0;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 1;
        case '^':
            return 2;
    }
}
```

Main code,

```
void main()
{
    char infix[50];
    char postfix[50];
    char c;
    char elem;

    stack S;

    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    CreateStack(&S);
    printf("Enter infix expression : ");
    scanf("%s", infix);

    while(!IsStackFull(&S)){
            c = infix[i];
            for(i=0; infix[i]='\0'; i++){
                if(c=='('){
                        Push(infix[i], &S);
                   }else if(isalnum(c)){
                        postfix[k++] = c;
                    }else if(c==')'){
                        while(Peek(&S)!='('){
                            Pop(&postfix[k++], &S);
                            Pop(&elem, &S);
                        }
                    }else{
                        while(Oprecedence(Peek(&S))>=Oprecedence(c)){
                            Pop(postfix[k++], &S);
                            Push(&c, &S);
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    while(!IsStackEmpty(&S)){
        Pop(&postfix[k++], &S);
    }
    postfix[k] = '\0';
    printf("\nPostfix Expression = %s\n", postfix);
}
```

And also I upload the question below check it,

[image: This is the question I have tried]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `if(c=='('){` where is `c` being given a value?

Comment: It is your repeated way of doing things - not using a debugger or a standard compiler or not even using  a notebook and a pen to go through your code? It is the second question by you asking to fix code without any source of error being narrowed down.

Comment: No bro, I am using Code blocks to compile this code, after changing the code It's not working, But the compiler doesn't giving me error!

Comment: `c = infix[i];` should be inside the for loop.

Comment: After putting c = infix[i]; inside the for loop, it's not working bro!

Comment: That button in your IDE that says "Debugger" would probably be real handy. Chances are it will be considerably more divulging than what we have ("it's not working" is is both non-informative an pointless to state; you wouldn't be here if it was working). When you debugged your program (you *did* do some debugging; *right*?) what did you discover?